# How to stop rendering each frame of a moving image onto the Surface in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a simple rainfall animation using pygame. I am moving the image downwards but updating it's rect.y position; however, each frame of the raindrop's movement is rendering onto the screen. A lot of sources point to that I would somehow have to refresh the screen at each frame, but where else should the position updates go?

Here is the full code:

```
import sys
import pygame
from raindrops import Raindrop
from pygame.sprite import Group 


def let_it_rain():
    '''initialize pygame, settings, and screen object'''
    pygame.init()
    screen_width = 1200
    screen_height = 800
    bg_color = (144, 177, 226)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Let It Rain")

    raindrop = Raindrop(screen)
    raindrops = Group()

    #number of drops in a row
    spacex = screen_width - (2 * raindrop.rect.width)
    raindrop_number_x = int(spacex / (2 * raindrop.rect.width))

    #start window for raindrops
    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        #create row of raindrops
        for raindrop_number in range(raindrop_number_x):
            raindrop = Raindrop(screen)
            raindrop.x = raindrop.rect.x + 2 * raindrop.rect.x * raindrop_number  
            raindrop.rect.x = raindrop.x
            raindrops.add(raindrop)

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        raindrops.update()
        raindrops.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

let_it_rain()
```

And the associated raindrops module:

```
import pygame
from pygame.sprite import Sprite


class Raindrop(Sprite):

    def __init__(self, screen):

        #load image
        super(Raindrop, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.pic = pygame.image.load('rain.png')
        self.image = pygame.transform.smoothscale(self.pic,(50,60))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        #starting position
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height

        #store exact decimal position of rainddrop
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def update(self):
        speed = 5
        self.y += speed 
        screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.rect.y = self.y
        #once raindrops reach the bottom of the screen, reposition to the top corrdinates
        if self.rect.y == screen_rect.bottom:
            self.y = 0
            self.rect.y = 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is move the for loop that creates raindrops before the while loop, like so:

```py
import sys
import pygame
from raindrops import Raindrop
from pygame.sprite import Group 


def let_it_rain():
    '''initialize pygame, settings, and screen object'''
    pygame.init()
    screen_width = 1200
    screen_height = 800
    bg_color = (144, 177, 226)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Let It Rain")

    raindrop = Raindrop(screen)
    raindrops = Group()

    #number of drops in a row
    spacex = screen_width - (2 * raindrop.rect.width)
    raindrop_number_x = int(spacex / (2 * raindrop.rect.width))

    #create row of raindrops
    for raindrop_number in range(raindrop_number_x):
        raindrop = Raindrop(screen)
        raindrop.x = raindrop.rect.x + 2 * raindrop.rect.x * raindrop_number  
        raindrop.rect.x = raindrop.x
        raindrops.add(raindrop)
    #start window for raindrops
    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

        

        screen.fill(bg_color)
        raindrops.update()
        raindrops.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.flip()

let_it_rain()
```

When it was inside the loop, it kept recreating the raindrops at every new y position